# Issues with Head First Android Example

Tags: java, android, updates

I'm trying to work through the Head First Android Development book and I'm running into a bit of a roadblock. I'm assuming the main cause of this is that the text is outdated, but my example keeps failing at runtime and I can't seem to find the reason. Here is the relevant files:

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.hfad.workout.MainActivity">

<fragment
    class="com.hfad.workout.WorkoutListFragment"
    android:id="@+id/list_frag"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></fragment>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.hfad.workout;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
WorkoutListFragment.WorkoutListListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public void itemClicked(long id) {
    WorkoutDetailFragment details = new WorkoutDetailFragment();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    details.setWorkout(id);
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, details);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
    ft.commit();
}

}
```

I can add the other files if they happen to be relevant. I already had issues with the "getFragmentManager" code but a quick search told me the updated code required to be used is "getSupportFragmentManager" so I changed that. It is also saying that the override for itemClicked is never used, but because there is a fragment list included (the id is "list_frag") this method should be built in, correct? I've been following the book exactly but the instances of outdated code keeps setting me back from learning.

Edit:

```
package layout;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.hfad.workout.Workout;

public class WorkoutListFragment extends ListFragment {


public WorkoutListFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

static interface WorkoutListListener {
    void itemClicked(long id);
};

private WorkoutListListener listener;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String[] names = new String[Workout.workouts.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        names[i] = Workout.workouts[i].getName();
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>  (inflater.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    this.listener = (WorkoutListListener)activity;
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    if (listener != null) {
        listener.itemClicked(id);
    }
}

}
```

Error:

Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]

C:\Users\reega\AndroidStudioProjects\Workout\app\src\main\java\com\hfad\workout\MainActivity.java

Error:(15, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 8.256 secs
Information:2 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console

Comment: I would suggest to go with developer.android.com tutorials. They are hands down best.

Comment: @SouravGanguly I had intended to go through them eventually also. But can you see what's wrong with the code above, any reason it wouldn't run?

Comment: Post fragment code and error log as well

Comment: I've posted the list fragment code and the errors.

Answer (score 0):

ListFragment has no onAttach method. The error says that you are trying to override the method of a superclass but there's no method to override.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html

Comment: Whenever I jump to the source of the error it leads me to the "itemClicked" method though? However I do see what you mean.